# WooCommerce Display Custom Taxonomy in archive

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, custom-taxonomy, hook-woocommerce

Trying to show the custom taxonomy "w_label" which I registered under products. However when I tried to display it with the code below:

```
register_taxonomy('w_label', array('product'), 
    array(  
        'hierarchical' => true, 
        'label' => 'Product Labels',
        'singular_label' => 'Product Label', 
        'rewrite' => true,
        'supports' => array('excerpt', 'thumbnail')

    )
);

function w_label_name () {
    global $post;
    $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'w_label' );
    foreach ( $terms as $term ){
      echo '<div class="label">' . $term->name . '</div>';
    }

}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'w_label_name', 2 );
```

I keep getting "Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()"

Not sure what I've missed. If I use this code for the default WooCommerce category it works, but not for custom taxonomy that I've registered here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First try to see if there is not a problem with `$terms = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'w_label');` try in your function this, to display `$terms`:

```
function w_label_name () {
    global $post;
    $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'w_label' );
    echo '<div class="label">' . var_dump($terms) . '</div>';
}
```

Then try also `get_terms( 'w_label' );` instead of `get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'w_label' );` and echo also `var_dump($terms)` with that to see what you are getting.

If you get something, the problem is coming from `$term->name` and the manner to get `$terms`. Then you could try this *(without any guaranty, because untested)*:

```
function w_label_name () {
    global $post;
    $terms = get_terms( 'w_label' );
    if ( ! empty( $terms ) && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ){
        foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
            echo '<div class="label">' . $term->name . '</div>';
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'w_label_name', 10 );
```

Comment: hey loic, i get an wpobject error. After some testing it lead me to changing to get_terms method since i created this custom taxonomy for this use case.

Answer (score 2):

This is my code that shows the labels correctly in a product loop:

```
function w_label_name () {
    global $post;
    $taxonomyName = "label_name";
    terms = get_terms( $taxonomyName, array( 'hide_empty' => 0) );
    echo '<div class="label"><ul>';
        foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
            ?><li><?php echo $term->name; ?></li><?php 
        }
    echo '</ul></div>';
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'w_label_name', 2 );
```

See also
[what is the difference between get_terms and get_the_terms in WordPress ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24925297/what-is-the-difference-between-get-terms-and-get-the-terms-in-wordpress)
for get_terms vs get_the_terms method